# Error opening shapefile with read_sf()

Tags: r, shapefile, sf

I'm trying to load a shapefile to R using the following code:

```
state_shape<- read_sf(file.path("C:/Users/ssaha/Documents"), layer="IND_adm1.shp")
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot open layer IND_adm1.shp
> Error: Opening layer failed.

I'm a newbie to the sf package.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, it should be `read_sf(file.path("C:/Users/ssaha/Documents", "IND_adm1.shp"))`

Comment: I updated it but now am getting this error message:

Error: Cannot open "C:\Users\ssaha\Documents\IND_adm1.shp"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.

Comment: Sure it shouldn't be `read_sf("C:/Users/ssaha/Documents/IND_adm1.shp")`  -- otherwise your file might actually be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> shp <- read_sf(dsn = 'C:/Users/ssaha/Documents/', layer = 'IND_adm1')

Let me know if this works.